# Filter out unique values from the cell that contains multiple values in Power BI table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a column in Power Bi table that contains multiple values and I want to create a new column that keeps the unique values only from the original one.

Example:

- if the multiple value is "Springfield, Springfield, Pueblo West", the new column should show "Springfield, Pueblo West".
- if the multiple value is "Springfield, Springfield, Springfield", the new column should show "Springfield".

Is there a way to create a calculated column that solves this?

This is the mage of the column and wanted result in red colour.

[image]

You can find sample data in PBI format at the next GDrive [**LINK**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/192nnadm21qEip-n7g2lebBeiRoKNV3wu/view?usp=share_link):

Comment: This type of data cleaning should be done in power query. Post sample data as text and either myself or someone else will show you how.

Comment: @DavidBacci I added a link to sample data in PBI format in my original post above.

Comment: I'll answer now. Please mark as solved and/or upvote for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click transform data from the ribbon. When in Power Query, click Add Column -> Custom Column. Paste in the following code:

```
Text.Combine( List.Distinct( List.Transform( Text.Split([City],","), each Text.Trim(_))),",")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about cells where the value repeats, like in your first row: "Wilkes-Barre, Wilkes-Barre"? The original ask was to eliminate that?

Comment: @Dolunaykiz - one is hyphenated and one is not. All identical values are removed to leave only distincts.

Comment: I missed that. You are correct.